# Input Text Change Color when typed

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do you change color if something is in an `<input>` tag
like if someone typed *no text*, **it would be a color** and if they typed some *text* **then another color**

Comment: could you please help me understand, how many different texts are possible?

Comment: ```   then your text ``` *  text   *  **  text  ** _   text    _

Comment: Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219088/1097415

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const title = document.querySelector('h1');

// Event is fired whenever someone types in the input
input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const { value } = e.target; // Get the value of the input
  const color = e.target.value ? 'green' : 'red'; // If there's no value, use green, otherwise, use red
  
  title.style.color = color;
})
```

```html
<input>
<h1>Title</h1>
```

In the future, please show what your markup looks like and what you have tried so we can help with *specific* issues.